# JWT authenticaton authorization not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to implement a jwt token to secure my APIs. I'm using Angular in frontend while using node and express in the backend with mongodb as database. I've tested my API and it seems to be generating a token but its not getting deleted after I logout or before even logging in I can still access some routes which I should not be able to do without login. In case if you want to have a better look at the project you can check out my git repository https://github.com/tridibc2/blog-admin-mean . When I'm logging in the I'm getting back this object:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Login Successful",
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "authToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqd3RpZCI6IkJNQllta011IiwiaWF0IjoxNTc4NDk3ODkwODA2LCJleHAiOjE1Nzg1ODQyOTAsInN1YiI6ImF1dGhUb2tlbiIsImlzcyI6ImVkQ2hhdCIsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlcklkIjoiN3FiYVhacVoiLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJYdHJlbWF0b3IiLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6ImRlIFNpbHZhIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ4dHJlbWF0b3JAcHViZy5jb20iLCJtb2JpbGVOdW1iZXIiOjk5MDkwOTkwOTl9fQ.KFyJAqaAygxL9IZNitAt5nt2naz8P7I6-JFCHwO4vdc",
        "userDetails": {
            "userId": "7qbaXZqZ",
            "firstName": "Xtremator",
            "lastName": "de Silva",
            "email": "xtremator@pubg.com",
            "mobileNumber": 9909099099
        }
    }
}
```

**Below are my Angular service functions**

```
public getUserInfoFromLocalStorage: any = () =>{
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
  }

  public setUserInfoInLocalStorage: any = (data) =>{
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  }

  public signinFunction(data): Observable<any>{

    const params = new HttpParams()

    .set('email', data.email)
    .set('password', data.password)


    return this._http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/login`, params);
  }
```

**Below is my login function and logout function which**

```
public logout() {
    this.blogpostService.logout().subscribe(
      data =>{
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      },
      error =>{
        console.log("some error occured");
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
    )

  }

public signinFunction: any = () => {
    if(!this.email){
      this.toastr.warning('Enter your email', 'Oops!');

    } else if(!this.password){
      this.toastr.warning('Enter your password', 'Oops!');

    } else {

      let data = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      } 
      this.blogpostService.signinFunction(data).subscribe((apiResponse) =>{
        console.log(apiResponse);
        if(apiResponse.status === 200){

          Cookie.set('authToken', apiResponse.data.authToken);
          Cookie.set('receiverId', apiResponse.data.userDetails.userId);
          Cookie.set('receiverName', apiResponse.data.userDetails.firstName + ' ' + apiResponse.data.userDetails.lastName);

          this.blogpostService.setUserInfoInLocalStorage(apiResponse.data.userDetails);
          this.router.navigate(['/admin/blog']);
        } else {
          this.toastr.error('Some Error Occured', 'Oops!');
        }

      }, (err) =>{
        this.toastr.error('Some Error Occured', 'Oops!');
        }
      )} //end of condition

  } //end of signinFunction
```

**Below are my node controller functions**

```
let loginFunction = (req, res) => {

    let findUser = () => {
        console.log("findUser");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (req.body.email) {
                console.log("req body email is there");
                console.log(req.body);
                UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email}, (err, userDetails) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        logger.error('Failed To Retrieve User Data', 'userController: findUser()', 10)
                        let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Failed To Find User Details', 500, null)
                        reject(apiResponse)
                    } else if (check.isEmpty(userDetails)) {
                        logger.error('No User Found', 'userController: findUser()', 7)
                        let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'No User Details Found', 404, null)
                        reject(apiResponse)
                    } else {
                        logger.info('User Found', 'userController: findUser()', 10)
                        resolve(userDetails)
                    }
                });

            } else {
                let apiResponse = response.generate(true, '"email" parameter is missing', 400, null)
                reject(apiResponse)
            }
        })
    }
    let validatePassword = (retrievedUserDetails) => {
        console.log("validatePassword");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            passwordLib.comparePassword(req.body.password, retrievedUserDetails.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    logger.error(err.message, 'userController: validatePassword()', 10)
                    let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Login Failed', 500, null)
                    reject(apiResponse)
                } else if (isMatch) {
                    let retrievedUserDetailsObj = retrievedUserDetails.toObject()
                    delete retrievedUserDetailsObj.password
                    delete retrievedUserDetailsObj._id
                    delete retrievedUserDetailsObj.__v
                    delete retrievedUserDetailsObj.createdOn
                    delete retrievedUserDetailsObj.modifiedOn
                    resolve(retrievedUserDetailsObj)
                } else {
                    logger.info('Login Failed Due To Invalid Password', 'userController: validatePassword()', 10)
                    let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Wrong Password.Login Failed', 400, null)
                    reject(apiResponse)
                }
            })
        })
    }

    let generateToken = (userDetails) => {
        console.log("generate token");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            token.generateToken(userDetails, (err, tokenDetails) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Failed To Generate Token', 500, null)
                    reject(apiResponse)
                } else {
                    tokenDetails.userId = userDetails.userId
                    tokenDetails.userDetails = userDetails
                    resolve(tokenDetails)
                }
            })
        })
    }


    let saveToken = (tokenDetails) => {
        console.log("save token");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            AuthModel.findOne({ userId: tokenDetails.userId }, (err, retrievedTokenDetails) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message, 'userController: saveToken', 10)
                    let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Failed To Generate Token', 500, null)
                    reject(apiResponse)
                } else if (check.isEmpty(retrievedTokenDetails)) {
                    let newAuthToken = new AuthModel({
                        userId: tokenDetails.userId,
                        authToken: tokenDetails.token,
                        tokenSecret: tokenDetails.tokenSecret,
                        tokenGenerationTime: time.now()
                    })
                    newAuthToken.save((err, newTokenDetails) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                            logger.error(err.message, 'userController: saveToken', 10)
                            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Failed To Generate Token', 500, null)
                            reject(apiResponse)
                        } else {
                            let responseBody = {
                                authToken: newTokenDetails.authToken,
                                userDetails: tokenDetails.userDetails
                            }
                            resolve(responseBody)
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    retrievedTokenDetails.authToken = tokenDetails.token
                    retrievedTokenDetails.tokenSecret = tokenDetails.tokenSecret
                    retrievedTokenDetails.tokenGenerationTime = time.now()
                    retrievedTokenDetails.save((err, newTokenDetails) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                            logger.error(err.message, 'userController: saveToken', 10)
                            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Failed To Generate Token', 500, null)
                            reject(apiResponse)
                        } else {
                            let responseBody = {
                                authToken: newTokenDetails.authToken,
                                userDetails: tokenDetails.userDetails
                            }
                            resolve(responseBody)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }


    findUser(req,res)
        .then(validatePassword)
        .then(generateToken)
        .then(saveToken)
        .then((resolve) => {
            let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 'Login Successful', 200, resolve)
            res.status(200)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("errorhandler");
            console.log(err);
            res.status(err.status)
            res.send(err)
        })

}


/**
 * function to logout user.
 * auth params: userId.
 */
let logout = (req, res) => {
    AuthModel.findOneAndRemove({userId: req.user.userId}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          logger.error(err.message, 'user Controller: logout', 10)
          let apiResponse = response.generate(true, `error occurred: ${err.message}`, 500, null)
          res.send(apiResponse)
      } else if (check.isEmpty(result)) {
          let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Already Logged Out or Invalid UserId', 404, null)
          res.send(apiResponse)
      } else {
          let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 'Logged Out Successfully', 200, null)
          res.send(apiResponse)
      }
    })
  } // end of the logout function.
```

the routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
   { path: 'admin/blog', component: ManageBlogsComponent },
   { path: 'admin/blog/create', component: CreateBlogComponent },
   { path: 'admin/blog/edit/:blogId', component: EditBlogComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips which will help you achieve what you wanted to:

1. Use session storage instead of local storage.
2. Use canActivate in routes and check whether the token has been generated or not.

Please share logout function and app routing file in the question, so that we can analyze it properly.